# Change mod nomination to 150 rep on SO

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I think this is a bug but on SO the requirement to nominate mods is 200 rep but at the last election it was 150 everywhere.

On other sites such as SU, it is 200 to.

Comment: What does a 50 rep difference even make?

Comment: @Earlz becuase I didn't vist the election page on SU becuase of that.

Comment: Heh. You have an interesting amount of MSO rep compared to SO rep. But anyway, I'd say 200 rep is not unfair. Just ask and answer a few more questions on SO and get up to 200 :)

Comment: Where are you getting these numbers from?

Comment: @Popular Demand the privileges pages

Comment: It seems to me that your definition of bug is "does the existing cutoff allow me to participate?" Unless and until you can provide a more convincing reason that the current number is bad and/or your proposed number is better, -1.

Comment: <sarcasm>Can the required reputation for down-voting a question be changed to 101, so that I can utilize that privilege?</sarcasm>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size, and more particularly the age, of the site matters.  As stackoverflow has grown, the reputation needed to vote in elections has increased.

The point is to find out what should be considered an active, productive, and interested member of the site, and let them vote.

On stackoverflow, which has existed for longer, and is more active, than the other sites it's not hard to contribute a few questions and answers, then quit the site for a year while those contributions gained reputation for you.

That's less likely to happen on other sites as they are smaller, get less traffic, and haven't been around quite as long.

So the bar is higher.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because all of the SE sites have gotten more users(and thus, more new users) and to combat it so that newer (I'm talking like one or two day old) users who don't know any of the nominees anyway, won't be able to vote. Some would argue that 200 is too low. I think it's about right, and it requires at least a full days work on the sites. (as in, you can accomplish it in one day by hitting the rep cap)

Answer (score 0):

This does seem to be a bug, but not the one the OP is thinking of. [This page](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-elections) says that users must have 200 rep to nominate a mod, but [this one](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=nomination) puts the figure at 300. I'm using CS Theory SE as an example, but the numbers are the same on several sites.

Comment: The privilege page title is confusing too, since it just says " *Participate* in moderator elections ", which is kind of vague. I don't see a separate privilege listed for *voting* in elections either, which happens at 150 rep.